# Get ID of current document Flutter / Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, crud

I have a list of books.
User can create reviews about those books. In a way to make the reviews publics, they need to be verified by staff.

This is how the reviews are created in Firestore :

```
  Future<void> addChapterReview() {
    return chapter_reviews
        .add({
          'anime_adaptation': animeAdaptation,
          'edited_in_france': editedInFrance,
          'link': chapterLinkController.text,
          'manga': chapterOriginalMangaController.text,
          'note': chapterNoteController.text,
          'number': chapterNumberController.text,
          'opinion': chapterOpinionController.text,
          'pic': chapterPicController.text,
          'title': chapterTitleController.text,
          'edited_in_france': isCheckedEdited,
          'anime_adaptation': isCheckedAnime,
          'isVerified': false,
        })
        .then((value) => print('Review ajoutée avec succès.'))
        .catchError((error) => print('Echec de l\'ajout de la review.'));
  }
```

After that, admins can check the reviews, validate, modify or delete them.

How I update the review :

```
  Future<void> sendValidation() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chapters")
        .doc("currentDocIdIWant")
        .update({'isVerified': 'true'});
  }
```

That where my problem is. To do any action on reviews, I need to get the current review's id.
I say 'current' because admin go on each review page to moderate them.

In example : I want to moderate a new posted review. I want to get this id :[image: screenshot example]

I can't find a solution that match with my code.

Don't hesitate to ask me mor details if needed.

**EDIT : OK so with the helpers below and some search, I can't get the id I want. So, I put the title in the ID when the review is created (no auto-generated ID). In this way, I can get and put the title of the current review I'm moderating in my moderation query.**

```
  Future<void> addChapterReview() {
    return chapter_reviews
        .doc(chapterTitleController.text)
        .set({
          'anime_adaptation': animeAdaptation,
          'edited_in_france': editedInFrance,
          'link': chapterLinkController.text,
          'manga': chapterOriginalMangaController.text,
          'note': chapterNoteController.text,
          'number': chapterNumberController.text,
          'opinion': chapterOpinionController.text,
          'pic': chapterPicController.text,
          'title': chapterTitleController.text,
          'edited_in_france': isCheckedEdited,
          'anime_adaptation': isCheckedAnime,
          'isVerified': 'false',
        })
        .then((value) => print('Review ajoutée avec succès.'))
        .catchError((error) => print('Echec de l\'ajout de la review.'));
  }
```

```
  Future<void> sendValidation() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chapters")
        .doc(widget.chapterdata['title'])
        .update({'isVerified': 'true'});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this:

```
QuerySnapshot feed =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("chapters").get();
    allDates = [];
    for (var element in feed.docs) {
        allDates.add(element.id);
    }
```

Doing this you'll get a list containing all the document ids in your **chapters** collection. Then you can use whichever you like :)

P.S. I'd recommend organizing your document ids and not to use auto-generated ones as they can add complexity in finding and addition or removal of others.

Comment: It is not exactly what I search. I have a page where there are all datas of a review, and want to get the id of this specific review. On the pic I have just a few reviews, but in the future I will have like 10 000.

Comment: You need to have some identifier which can be an id or something so you can use functions like `where()` method

Comment: why don't you add your reviews by specifying count of them? like if you want the 13th review then its document id should be 13, right?

Comment: I want to avoid to have too much data in the reviews because of the futur amount. I will think about it if I don’t have any other solution !

Comment: Maybe I will try with a already existing data like the title.

Comment: like you need to have something or else you won't be able to distinguish them from each other

Answer (score 1):

```
  Future<void> addChapterReview() {
    final documentAdded =
        await chapter_reviews.add({
          'anime_adaptation': animeAdaptation,
          'edited_in_france': editedInFrance,
          'link': chapterLinkController.text,
          'manga': chapterOriginalMangaController.text,
          'note': chapterNoteController.text,
          'number': chapterNumberController.text,
          'opinion': chapterOpinionController.text,
          'pic': chapterPicController.text,
          'title': chapterTitleController.text,
          'edited_in_france': isCheckedEdited,
          'anime_adaptation': isCheckedAnime,
          'isVerified': false,
        });
    final savedDocumentID = documentAdded.id;
}
```

You can do whatever you want with that ID

Comment: I don’t know if it will works because according to you answer, the id is store in a different page. 
To better understand, I have a page where user writes review (where your answer is located) and a page where admin can moderate it. Imagine like it’s a product’s details page in an e-shop. I want the id of the product of the page.